# How to find if some words in array value are in same array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 18:25:00
            [artist] => LUIS RODRIGUEZ
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 18:34:00
            [artist] => THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [time] => 18:37:00
            [artist] => THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [time] => 18:44:00
            [artist] => J BALVIN
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [time] => 18:44:00
            [artist] => LUIS RODRIGUEZ & DEN HARROW
        )

)
```

I want to check if some word are contains in other array values so

```
J BALVIN is in 1,2,3
LUIS RODRIGUEZ in in 0 and 4
```

So how can I find if the value of artist is similar to other?
I want the result can say me where are similar words and get also the time.
I try with array_intersect but it doesn't work

with a loop I can find the value

```
$input = array(array('time' => '18:44:00', 'artist' => 'LUIS RODRIGUEZ & DEN HARROW'), array('time' => '18:45:00', 'artist' => 'J BALVIN'), array('time' => '18:34:00', 'artist' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN'), array('time' => '18:37:00', 'artist' => 'THE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVIN'), array('time' => '18:44:00', 'artist' => 'J BALVIN'));

foreach ($input as $inputs) {
    $time = $inputs['time'];
    $artist = $inputs['artist'];
}
```

but how can I can compare the string?
If I use in_array the result is not what I want

```
foreach ($input as $inputs) {
    $time = $inputs['time'];
    $artist = $inputs['artist'];

    if (in_array($artist, $inputs)) {
        echo $artist . '<br>';
    }
}
```

I have to change all my method, but the @Barmar suggestion help me to improve my new functions, so you can check [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240118/find-if-some-words-in-array-value-are-in-same-array-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? How exactly are you planning on tokenizing individual entities in the `artist` field in order to look for them in other arrays? Show us your best effort up to this point, and point out exactly where your code isn't working.

Comment: Use nested loops. The outer loop gets the `artist` value of the current element, the inner loop searches all the other elements looking for a match.

Comment: @Barmar so how can I compare? Thanks

Comment: @esqew, thanks I edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$inputs` is not an array of strings, it's a 2-dimensional array, so you can't use `in_array()` to search it.

You can use `array_column()` to create an array of all the artists, and search that.

You can't use `in_array()` for the search, since it does an exact match. Loop over it and call `strstr()` to test if the current artists is a substring.

```
$artists = array_column($input, 'artist');
foreach ($input as $inputs) {
    $time = $inputs['time'];
    $artist = $inputs['artist'];

    foreach ($artists as $index => $a) {
        if (strstr($a, $artist)) {
            echo "$artist is in $index";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but I don't find where a string contains an other string

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that part.

Comment: Hi, with I have all the string... but not which contains other ```LUIS RODRIGUEZ & DEN HARROWJ BALVINTHE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVINTHE BLACK EYED PEAS FT J BALVINJ BALVIN```

Comment: I added that. But why couldn't you figure that out yourself? I'm not doing anything very advanced.

Comment: Hi, because with your method I can find if any string (in this case artist) are in other string, so I try to do with a simple query in database, but I cannot find if a part of string in other string.

Comment: I had the arguments to `strstr` backwards.

Comment: So with this, as you explain me,  you test if the current artists is a substring, but not if the current artist has some similar with other

Comment: I try to change some values, but with this method I can only see if a string is in  one other, but not if some words for example LUIS RODRIGUEZ & DEN HARROW has some characters similar to LUIS RODRIGUEZ

Comment: This only looks for an exact substring, not similar words. That's much harder.

Comment: I have a new solution, it was quite impossible find the string and substring, so I have some string delimiter, so can I post the new question with delimeter? I edit the initial post or I answer the question to add all my code? Thanks

Comment: If you have the solution, why do you need to post another question?

Comment: Because I would ask you to check it

Comment: This isn't a proofreading service. If it has problems, you can ask for help fixing them.

Comment: So I have now 5 foreach loop, so I want to check if there is a more compact solution and maybe someone can you use the solution. Thanks

Comment: [codereview.se] is the place to ask for improvements to working code.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post with the link of the working code

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```php
function findIndexesByArtist($array, $name) {
    return array_keys(array_filter($array, function($item) {
       return (strpos($item['artist'], $name) !== false);
    }));
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand how use it

Comment: findIndexesByArtist($yourArray, "Who are you searchig for"); - returns array of indexes of these items that contain this artist